# using ajax to update data on modal form with php mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

i manage to prevent my modal form from closing after submiting value using
ajax jQuery without page refreshing,

but now my problem is when i fill in my modal form and click submit to update the data inside my database is not updating.

i think there's something wrong of my ajax code.

hope you can help me. thanks.

**here is my code:**

```
 <form class="needs-validation " id="contact-form" action="index13.php" method="post" novalidate >
</form>
```

**here is my index13.php code:**

```
<?php

 include_once ('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{

$username2 = $_POST['username2'];
$password1= $_POST['password1'];
$time=date("H:i:s");

$sql = "select * from visitor_att  where  uname = '$username2' and pass = '$password1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 0) {

echo "No Results";

    } else{
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $username2 = $row['uname'];
          $password1 = $row['pass'];
          $fname=$row['fname'];
          $lname=$row['lname']; 

         $InsertSql = "Update visitor_att set timeout = '$time' where  uname = '$username2' and pass = '$password1'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 

        }

         }



  }
?>
```

**here is my ajax jQuery code:**

```
<script>    
$(function() {


 var frm = $("#contact-form");

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr("post"),
            url: frm.attr("action"),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

when i run it on console it shows Submission was successful.
but no data is inserted in database.

Comment: is  your data shown in console or not???

Comment: after submit ? no data shown

Comment: use console after var frm = $("#contact-form");   console(frm); and let me know

Comment: Does data entered to the db?

Comment: @Mohit Kumar when i run var frm = $("#contact-form"); it says undefine , and console(frm) frm not define

Comment: @Ramesh data not entered to database

Comment: because you cannot set username and password in your update query with set attribute

Comment: is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: change ur update query.

Comment: can you help me fix it ?

Comment: try this        Update visitor_att set uname = '$username2' and pass = '$password1' where  uname = '$username2'";

Comment: i have an timein and timeout inside my sample databse, the query update im using it to update data that on timeout col

Comment: Add the following code at the top of the PHP file to display errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); display_errors = on;` or check the `errors_log` file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the id attribute to your form as your ajax call is bound to it...

```
<form id="contact-form" class="needs-validation" action="index13.php" method="post" novalidate >
```

Comment: How could the result be the same? Your ajax call would never have fired the way you originally posted it.

Comment: what i mean i just forgot to add the id when i posted my question

Comment: Well ok, I guess I wasted my pointless answer then. Next time you post, please post all the facts to prevent us from having egg on our face... (an upvote would have been nice).

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: Thats OK, at least you know the next time around.